# BaseX: correct syntax to place multiple 'replace '

Tags: xquery, basex

```
declare function local:stripNS($name as xs:string?)
as xs:string?
{
  if(contains($name, ':'))
  then substring($name, functx:index-of-string($name, ':') + 1)
  else $name
};

for $x in doc("test.xml")//*[@ref]
let $tmp:=local:stripNS($x/@ref)
return replace value of node $x/@ref with $tmp
```

I want to strip namespace from the value of `ref` and `type` attribute. SO `<test ref='haha:123' type='hehe:456'/>` should become `<test ref='123' type='456'/>`. I don't know the correct syntax, below is the ideal .xqy file I want:

```
declare function local:stripNS($name as xs:string?)
as xs:string?
{
  if(contains($name, ':'))
  then substring($name, functx:index-of-string($name, ':') + 1)
  else $name
};

for $x in doc('test.xml')//*[@ref]
let $tmp:=local:stripNS($x/@ref)
return replace value of node $x/@ref with $tmp,

for $x in doc('test.xml')//*[@type]
let $tmp:=local:stripNS($x/@type)
return replace value of node $x/@ref with $tmp
```

But obviously it contains syntax error:

> [XUDY0017] Node can only be replaced once: attribute ref {"123"}.

`$ basex -u test.xqy`

Use the command above to test. The output would be written back to `test.xml`.

Comment: Please always provide some example input. Makes life easier for those answering questions, and gives answers better fitting your actual problem in return.

Comment: @JensErat You already have it. Just copy and paste the `<test ref='haha:123' type='hehe:456'/>` to a local file called `test.xml`

Comment: Indeed. Another thing even more important you missed: **always** include the error message if you get one. If you'd posted the error message, probably most XQuery folks around here would've spotted the issue right away without even copying the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're having is a typo in the second flwor expression: you try to replace the same attribute twice.

```
for $x in doc('test.xml')//*[@type]
let $tmp:=local:stripNS($x/@type)
return replace value of node $x/@ref with $tmp
                             (: ^^^^ should be @type :)
```

Anyway, your query is overly complex. First of all, XQuery knows a [`substring-after($string, $token)`](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_substring-after.html) function which you're rewriting yourself. So you can cut down your function to

```
declare function local:stripNS($name as xs:string?)
as xs:string?
{
  if(contains($name, ':'))
  then substring-after($name, ':')
  else $name
};
```

while at the same time removing the functx dependency.

Furthermore, you can also select multiple, different attributes with a single query, simplifying the query to

```
for $attribute in doc('test.xml')//(@ref, @type)
return replace value of node $attribute with local:stripNS($attribute)
```

Finally, adding a simple `where` clause lets you give up the whole function (and reducing the number of updates attributes at the same time, which would speed up the query for large documents):

```
for $attribute in doc('test.xml')//(@ref, @type)
where contains($attribute, ':')
return replace value of node $attribute with substring-after($attribute, ':')
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query should do the job:

```
declare function local:stripNS($name as xs:string) as xs:string {
  replace($name, "^.*:", "")
};

for $attr in doc('test.xml')//*/(@ref, @type)
let $tmp := local:stripNS($attr)
return replace value of node $attr with $tmp
```